# Are these identical for the two notations representing Conditional probability of three varibles

Tags: probability

Notation 1: $P(A|B|C)$
Notation 2: $P(A|B,C)$

I think these are identical. For Notation 1. $P(A,B,C)=P(A|B|C)P(B|C)P(C)$, So,

$P(A,B,C)=P(A|B|C)P(B,C)$, and

$P(A,B,C)=P(A|B,C)P(B,C)$, So Notation 2 and Notation 1 are identical.

But it is weird. Can anybody explain to me?

Comment: As long as the notation is clear and well stated to the audience it can look however makes the most sense to you. That being said, the 2nd notation convention you use is considered pretty standard in the study of random variables.

Comment: "Notation 1: P(A|B|C)" seems to be your own invention (is it?). Afterwards, you *define* P(A|B|C) as P(A|B|C)=P(A,B,C)/(P(B|C)P(C)), thus P(A|B|C)=P(A,B,C)/P(B,C)=P(A|B,C).

Comment: @Did Notation 1 is not my invention, you can find it in an [article](http://moodle.technion.ac.il/pluginfile.php/179706/mod_resource/content/0/2010/particle-filters1.pdf),the equation 45. Besides, I don't know how it is been defined.

Comment: @jameselmore but $P(A|B|C)$ is used in some articles, and I don't how it is been defined. I just give my hypotheses

Comment: Notation 1 appears only at one place (equation (45), page 178) in a paper choke-full of Bayesian stuff... Other oddities in the paper are the notations $p(x(y,z)$ and $p(x|y(z)$. Typos, perhaps? Anyway, let me suggest to stick to the standard notations P(A|B,C) and p(x|y,z).

Comment: @Did it is an article cited by 8078 times...I was totally crazy about its notations, suspecting the authority of IEEE.